# Sales - Reporting - Sales: psycopg2.DataError: division by zero

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-11

When I click on Sales menu under Sale->Reporting menu then I got the following error message:

> Error: Odoo Server Error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 650, in _handle_exception
>       return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
>       raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py",
>   line 87, in reraise
>       raise value   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 692, in dispatch
>       result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 342, in _call_function
>       return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
>       return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 335, in checked_call
>       result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 936, in **call**
>       return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
>       response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 934, in call_kw
>       return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 926, in
>   _call_kw
>       return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 687, in call_kw
>       return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_model
>       result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1908, in read_group
>       result = self._read_group_raw(domain, fields, groupby, offset=offset, limit=limit, orderby=orderby, lazy=lazy)   File
>   "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1998, in _read_group_raw
>       self._cr.execute(query, where_clause_params)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 155, in wrapper
>       return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/data/odoo/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 232, in execute
>       res = self._obj.execute(query, params) psycopg2.DataError: division by zero

Anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have some weird data letting postgres do some division by zero. If you're talking about `sale.report` my first guess is: You're using some unit of measures with `factor == 0`.

```sql
sum(p.weight * l.product_uom_qty / u.factor * u2.factor) as weight,
sum(p.volume * l.product_uom_qty / u.factor * u2.factor) as volume
```

Currency is my second guess. Did you check all rates for every company? Also there was a commit for Odoo 11 in Dec 2018 which was fixing the zero currency rate problem. So you can also try to use the newest Odoo version and update sale

Comment: Thank you for this.
I have multi company setup. For some companies it is working fine while for two company it is throwing this error message.

There is no UOM which factor is zero.

And I also checked, there is no currency whose rate is zero.

Comment: Currency was my second guess. Did you check all rates for every company? Also there was a commit for Odoo 11 in Dec 2018 which was fixing the zero currency rate problem. So you can also try to use the newest Odoo version and update `sale`.

Comment: Thank you. There was zero currency rate issue for two of the companies.

Comment: added that in the answer. Thanks for the response.